# How do I prevent Arcmap from verifying SQL expressions when using a plugin dataset?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, sql, plugins

I've written a plugin workspace for ArcGIS.

I'm able to compose a where clause containing syntax that my implementation of IPluginDatasetHelper understands, assign it to IQueryFilter.Whereclause, and get the expected results from ITable.Search.

However, if I copy and paste the same whereclause into into the layer query Definition expression editor, it fails to verify.  Arcmap complains that it is not SQL.  In this case, the expression never makes it to my plugin.

Is there someway I can escape my definition expression in Arcmap so that it lets the plugin validate he expression?

Comment: Related? [How to Comment Out Definition Queries](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45235/how-to-comment-out-definition-queries)